# Blank pages at joomla backend,error 404,not saving changes

Tags: joomla

Blank article page.
Errors found listed below .I'm a beginner with joomla I'm lost on a project now .at First was error 404 after update to joomla 2.5.9 ,now i cant even access ,the articles.I'm getting blank pages from admin pages of the backend.Is dere a way i can copy all the articles out from the folder directory of gantry/joomla. If yes I can start building the website all over again. please help anybody Deadline for site to go live is tommorrow.,

`Strict Standards: Declaration of JCacheControllerPage::store() should be compatible with JCacheController::store($data, $id, $group = NULL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417\libraries\joomla\cache\controller\page.php on line 199`

`Strict Standards: Only variab,les should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417\plugins\system\rokgallery\rokgallery.php on line 22`

`Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417\plugins\system\rokgallery\rokgallery.php on line 23`

`Warning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417/components/com_content/helpers/route.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417\plugins\finder\content\content.php on line 330`

`Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417/components/com_content/helpers/route.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417\plugins\finder\content\content.php on line 330`

`Fatal error: Class 'ContentHelperRoute' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417\plugins\finder\content\content.php on line 273`

`Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417/components/com_content/helpers/route.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417\administrator\templates\hathor\html\com_content\articles\modal.php on line 17`

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417/components/com_content/helpers/route.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gantry417\administrator\templates\hathor\html\com_content\articles\modal.php on line 17`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the permission to the `route.php` file.
2. Make sure the `route.php` file exists on the mentioned path.

Comment: can you tell from where i can get the route.php in joomla.

Answer (score 0):

The route.php file is not there / is not readable.

1. download the update package 2.5.9 http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/17967/78436/Joomla_2.5.x_to_2.5.9-Stable-Patch_Package.zip and explode it over your current site;
2. clear the cache/* folder
3. re-assign permissions (chown -R user:group *)
4. you should now be able to access administrator.

If you can also access the frontend, you're done.
Else assign one of the default templates (i.e. beez) and you should be able to see the website

If the latter works, then most likely you have a wrong gantry, re-download the right version of the template for your website.

If it doesn't, simply reinstall it there may be something wrong.